# Problem in creating advanced profile in magento enterprise 1.9.0.0

Tags: php, magento

Test conducted in Magento Enterprise version 1.9.0.0
First Problem
When I try to create new profile under Advanced profile in admin and try to save it, I get following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget::getrowurl() in D:\wamp\www\ent\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php on line 1583
```

As I started to drill down into the code and reach to   app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Widget\Grid.php  in line no. 1583, I have found following chunk of code (green color):

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget {

    public function getRowUrl($item)
    {
        $res = parent::getRowUrl($item);
        return ($res ? $res : '#');
    }
}
```

If you see `$res = parent::getRowUrl($item);` In the code, it instruct to run `getRowUrl()` function from its parent class i.e. `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget`. Now when I search getRowUrl function in the widget class, it is not available there, even not in the parent class of Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget.

I also tried to debug by commenting the code written getRowUrl() function, but it doesn’t work.

Second problem:
When I run normal profile to import all product, I see following error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Abstract::getexceptions() in D:\wamp\www\ent\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Convert\Profile\Run.php on line 166
```

All I tested this in fresh enterprise version 1.9.0.0 without installing any extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you found a bug.  If you have Enterprise Edition, then I recommend that you use the support agreement and contact Magento Inc.  Please post what the fix is once they help you out.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a problem with that, but I did discover another bug in the advanced profile in which the layout is never loaded. I did confirm this with Magento and they are aware of the bug. in app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/dataflow.xml

You need to add the following otherwise you get a blank admin screen.

```
 <adminhtml_system_convert_profile_run>
    <remove name="root"/>
    <block type="adminhtml/page" name="convert_root" output="toHtml" template="page.phtml">
        <block type="adminhtml/page_head" name="convert_root_head" as="head" template="page/head.phtml">
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/validation.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>varien/js.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/translate.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>mage/adminhtml/tools.js</script></action>
        </block>
        <block type="adminhtml/system_convert_profile_run" name="system_convert_profile_run" template="system/convert/profile/process.phtml" output="toHtml"/>
    </block>
</adminhtml_system_convert_profile_run>
```

As for your errors, I don't think this is a bug, since we haven't had a problem on any of our 1.9 installs. I do see what you are talking about it not being in the parent, but the only thing that calls the method inside the grid class is a deprecated method getRowId, which I don't see anything else calling it besides a grid.phtml file that is used on the dashboard.